# How to disable horizontal scrolling in crystal seek bar Android

Tags: java, android

I am using crystal seekbar for horizontal scroll but i need to disable the scrolling...I have relative layout with crystakseekbar inside relative layout with disable mode so don't want to scroll the crystalseekbar when layout in disable mode.

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/adjust_card_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/adjust_card_disable_background"
            android:layout_below="@+id/card_layout"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="40dp"
            android:paddingTop="40dp">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/adjust_text_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/select_card_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/select_card"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:visibility="visible"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/adjust_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Adjust values for"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/shop_visit_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="First Shop"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/adjust_text"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/adjust_text_layout"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/adjust_hours_layout"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/adjustHours"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Adjust Hours"
                            android:textAllCaps="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="15sp"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/adjust_hours"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"/>


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/adjust_hours"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:background="#A2B0BE"
                            android:paddingLeft="40dp"
                            android:paddingRight="40dp"
                            android:paddingTop="5dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <com.crystal.crystalrangeseekbar.widgets.CrystalSeekbar
                        android:id="@+id/rangeSeekbar1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/adjust_hours_layout"
                        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                        app:bar_color="@color/hours_back"
                        app:bar_highlight_color="@color/btn_back"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        app:left_thumb_color="@color/white"
                        app:left_thumb_color_pressed="@color/white"
                        app:corner_radius="05"
                        app:data_type="_integer"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textMin1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="MIN"
                        android:layout_below="@id/rangeSeekbar1"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rangeSeekbar1"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                        android:textSize="13dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textMax1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="MAX"
                        android:layout_below="@id/rangeSeekbar1"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:textSize="13dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/rangeSeekbar1"
                        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"/>

                </RelativeLayout>



                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/adjust_mr_layout"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/adjustMr"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Adjust Mr"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/adjust_mr"/>


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/adjust_mr"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:background="#A2B0BE"
                        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
                        android:paddingRight="40dp"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <com.crystal.crystalrangeseekbar.widgets.CrystalSeekbar
                        android:id="@+id/rangeSeekbar2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/adjust_mr_layout"
                        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                        app:bar_color="#A2B0BE"
                        app:bar_highlight_color="@color/btn_back"
                        app:left_thumb_color="@color/white"
                        app:left_thumb_color_pressed="@color/white"
                        app:corner_radius="05"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        app:data_type="_integer"

                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textMin2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="MIN"
                        android:layout_below="@id/rangeSeekbar2"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rangeSeekbar2"
                        android:textSize="13dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textMax2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="MAX"
                        android:layout_below="@id/rangeSeekbar2"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:textSize="13dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/rangeSeekbar2"
                        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"/>


                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

          </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Add some code snippets also

Comment: @Nizam Parent Relative layout is disable(gray out).when i click or scroll crystalseekbar its getting scroll.I just want to disable crystalseekbar also.

Comment: Did you try disabling crystalseekbar itself, instead of the parent layout?

Comment: @Nizam no..i disabled  parents layout also

Comment: Disable crystalseekbar. `seekbar.setEnabled(false);`

Comment: @Nizam Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the parent layout is OK. But this will not disable the inner children. To disable the seekbar, you have to write `seekbar.setEnabled(false);`